# Webdriver - page get freezed and some of the network calls are not triggering properly after click events.(A general question)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

This is a general question, while troubleshooting automation scripts , 
I had seen that , in webdriver's chrome browser only some of the network calls are not triggering properly after corresponding successful click events.

One thing I could assume is that since webdriver running on a fresh instance , this could occur.
From your experience, if you had faced this , please tell me what were  the reasons  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this specific scenario based on the analysis, some of the responses are not triggered in webdriver browser instance and chrome's incognito . It's an issue in the application itself .